# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression when using window.location

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jquery version 2.2.0. I am getting following error. I Just Clicking on a button. it is throwing following error

Code in JS :

```
function ProductImport(ImportType) 
    {
           window.location = '/Mpa/ImportData/Index/?ObjectType=Product';
    }
```

Jquery :

```
 Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
    throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};
```

Error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #?ObjectType=Product
    at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery.js?v=A5AzdeUZJBV1X2MpcCLHI_iCCTFSpBAn2RvZthKq5AM:1463)

Comment: what function are you trying too call? Where is the code for it?

Comment: I think it's safe to say that `window.location =` is *not* causing your sizzle error, even in jquery 2.2.  Just to confirm: https://jsfiddle.net/0qaLn14j/  There's some other code you've not provided here causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks you are right is not issue of window.location . It was due to another code...